# OAuth2 Implicit Grant with Mobile App (URI quetsion)

Tags: docusignapi

I'm writing a mobile app for a DocuSign client using PhoneGap (i.e. with JavaScript, HTML5, CSS3). I created a DocuSign integration key and selected `This is a mobile app`.  However, DocuSign is requesting a URI.  My URI will be a file in a folder (e.g. `/DocuSign/callback.html`).  When I try to enter my URI without a domain name DocuSign with not save the path to my file.  Is a URI required to have a domain name for mobile apps using the OAuth2 Implicit Grant method?  If so, how do I add a URI to my integration key without a domain name?

Comment: For mobile apps you can set the redirect_uri to localhost (e.g. http://localhost/callback).  You don't need a public URL when developing a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one of the OAuth2.0 authorization flows in your integration then you will need provide an publicly accessible return URL for so the DocuSign authentication service knows where to redirect the user once they are done logging in through the standard DocuSign login flow.  This way your app does not need to manage or eve ask for your users' account passwords which is one of the main advantages of OAuth.

Alternatively if you want to build a service integration where authentication is take care of in the backend and there's an account "tied" to the integration you can use the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` which does not require a redirect URI.

Learn more about DocuSign [authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html).